# Execute rest resource for post method from workbench

Tags: apex, apexrest, superbadges

I am working on Data Integration Specialist Superbage, 
created below apex class with post method, I want to see the inputs from the workbench, but I am getting an error

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/project/*')
global class ProjectRESTService {
    //Implement service logic here
    @httpPost
    global static void postProjectData(String ProjectRef, String ProjectName,String OpportunityId, Date StartDate,Date EndDate, Double Amount,String Status ){
        System.debug('ProjectRef::'+ProjectRef);
        System.debug('ProjectName:'+ProjectName);
        System.debug('OpportunityId::'+OpportunityId);
        System.debug('StartDate:'+StartDate);
        System.debug('EndDate::'+EndDate);
        System.debug('Amount:'+Amount);
        System.debug('Status:'+Status);
    }
}
```

Workbench Error
[image]

Please suggest what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON keys and string values should be in double quotes, try double quotes instead of single quotes.